# If function is called with null or undefined show error, else return value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that return error or value. If argument is NULL or undefined throw error.
whats wrong with this ?:

```
function get(value){
 if (value == null){
  return false;
 }
 else {
  return value;
 }
}
```

Comment: Where are you throwing the error?

Comment: It's up to you to tell us what's wrong with your code, then maybe we can help you. As it stands, the code seems correct, except you `return false` instead of throwing an error, which could be correct but would give you ambiguous results : if the result is `false`, was the input `undefined`/`null`, or was it `false` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't understand the requirement 100%, but in order to produce en error, you can use the "throw" keyword:

```
function get(val) {
    if (val == null) {
        throw 'Value is eithr null or undefined';
    }
    return val;
}
```